# Upgrading Xdebug error Can't locate Autom4te/C4che.pm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

When setting up PhpStorm and configuring Xdebug I get the following error:

```
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220121212. The Zend Engine API 
version 320151012 which is installed, is newer. Contact Derick Rethans 
at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.
```

I'm running Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

UPDATE:

Following @alix-blex advise to compile a new version, I use the following to determine what steps to take:

https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

So while compiling a new version of Xdebug and running the following commands I get an error:

```
wget http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.5.4.tgz
tar -xvzf xdebug-2.5.4.tgz
cd xdebug-2.5.4
phpize
```

Then I get this error

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
Can't locate Autom4te/C4che.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Autom4te::C4che module) (@INC contains:
/usr/local/share/autoconf
/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Network/Library/Perl/5.18
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2
/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /usr/local/bin/autom4te line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/autom4te line 37.
```

FINALLY (worked after)

```
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew install php70-xdebug
sudo vi /usr/local/php7/lib/php.ini

(insert into php.ini)
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php70-xdebug/2.5.5/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1

sudo apachectl restart
```

Thanks for your help @alex-blex

Comment: What version of Xdebug have you downloaded?

Comment: My phpinfo() says xdebug version 2.5.3

Comment: Have you read the page behind the link?  > If you are using a pre-compiled binary, then you're using the wrong one.

Comment: I am using the wrong one. So do I need to compile a new one?

Comment: Either, compile one yourself, or get a precompiled one that matches your php version.

Comment: While attempting to compile I am running: 
    wget http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.5.4.tgz
    tar -xvzf xdebug-2.5.4.tgz
    cd xdebug-2.5.4
    phpize
---- Then I get this error ----
    PHP Api Version:         20151012
    Zend Module Api No:      20151012
    Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
    Can't locate Autom4te/C4che.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Autom4te::C4che module)

Comment: so install autoconf, as the error suggest: `brew install automake`, `port install autoconf` or manually.